# I need help with this review question. Business Calculus/Statistics

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

The question is: The scores on a test have a mean of 100 and a standard deviation of 8. A personnel manager wishes to select the top 60% of applicants. Find the cutoff score. Assume the variable is normally distributed.

What I don't know: I don't know how to set up this problem. 
I know z = (x - mean) / Standard deviation

so its z = (x - 100) / 8 and I am looking for x, the cutoff score.
How should z look like?
Its looking for the top 60% so the answer will be less than the mean because its the same as looking for the cutoff score for the bottom 40%.
Is 95.2 = x the correct answer (I used -.6 as z to get that), or is 96.8 (-.4 used as z) the correct answer? or are neither of those correct? This is the only problem I missed and I'm just not sure what z needs to be set as. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the idea of how to do it correctly.  You just need to find the correct value $z$ such that $\Pr(Z<z)=.4$.  After looking online at some tables, I found the value to be somewhere around $-0.25$.  This would give the cutoff score of $x=98$.

Comment: Now I realize that I need to look for the z value that has the closest probability to .4 inside the table. Thanks.

Comment: You got it! No problem.